# How to do dequentize with the output of quantized tflite?

Tags: quantization, tensorflow-lite

I have convert a **PB** file to **tflite** with **uint8** quantization. I would like to know how to convert the output from **uint8** back to float so that the previous code can still work.

Comment: Please provide your code sample.

Comment: Hi Liao, which language are you using? (E.g. Java on Android? C++ API through Objective C on iOS?)

Comment: I am using TensorFlow Lite on Android. the codes is like:

tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);

where tflite is Interpreter. The image data is input and get a multi-dimensions output array. I do further calculation with the output array data. I would like to know how can I use original codes that work on float type output for the uint8 output now. The idea is that do the dequantize from float to uint8 but how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the range of float is `[-1..1]`, so the formula is

```
putFloat((uint8Val - 127.5)/127.5)
```

But this actually depends on the quantization parameters [mean and std](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527964/192373) you used. Note that recently *tflite* [switched to int8](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec) in range `[-128..127]`.