# Why the execution time of quantized Uint8 TF-lite model is slower than F32 version?

Tags: tensorflow, quantization, tensorflow-lite

I am using TF1.12 to convert a simple mnist model with two conv2d layers to TF-lite.

```
F32:

`*tflite_convert --output_file model_lite/conv_net_f32.tflite \
 --graph_def_file frozen_graphs/conv_net.pb  \
 --input_arrays "input" \
 --input_shapes "1,784" \
 --output_arrays output \
 --output_format TFLITE*`

UINT8:
 tflite_convert --output_file model_lite/conv_net_uint8.tflite \
 --graph_def_file frozen_graphs/conv_net.pb  \
 --input_arrays "input" \
 --input_shapes "1,784" \
 --output_arrays output \
 --output_format TFLITE \
 --mean_values 0\
 --std_dev_values 255\
 --default_ranges_min 0 \
 --default_ranges_max 255 \
 --inference_type QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
 --inference_input_type QUANTIZED_UINT8*
```

However I found the execution time of quantized uint8 version is slower than f32.

Results:

[image: Results:]

It does not make sense to me.

Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks for any inputs!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try conversion with following command:

```
 tflite_convert --output_file model_lite/conv_net_uint8.tflite \
 --graph_def_file frozen_graphs/conv_net.pb  \
 --input_arrays "input" \
 --input_shapes "1,784" \
 --output_arrays output \
 --output_format TFLITE \
 --mean_values 128\
 --std_dev_values 127
 --default_ranges_min 0 \
 --default_ranges_max 1 \
 --inference_type QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
 --inference_input_type QUANTIZED_UINT8*
```

`default_ranges_min` and `default_ranges_max` correspond to maximum and minimum values of your network, as in the range of your activation functions.
If you are using activation such as `relu6`, you should change `default_ranges_max` to `6`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261772/tensorflow-lite-toco-mean-values-std-values) Stack Overflow question for information about `mean_values` and `std_dev_values`. They depend on your training data.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the params, it may effect to accuracy, but seems not to performance (execute time).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the hardware has special support for fast 8 bit instructions, quantized models are not expected to be any faster than FP32 models
Eg . tflite `uint8` models runs with same speed as that of `fp32` on raspi `aarch64` as it is arm7 device